# How to set optional locale parameter in Next.js v13 routes?

Tags: next.js, internationalization

I'm building an app using Next.js version 13 and am implementing internationalization. I'd like the default locale to be en-US. To achieve this, I've created a middleware that redirects users who aren't on a path like /[locale]..., unless their locale is en-US, in which case I'd prefer not to redirect them and instead allow them to continue on /....

The issue I'm facing is that Next.js seems not to accept routes with only some optional parameters. What I want is a route like /[locale?]/lesson/[lesson] where [lesson] is mandatory but [locale] is optional.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior in Next.js?

Answer (score -1):

You can use optional parameters by wrapping them in double square brackets. Try something like this: **[[...locale]]**/lesson/[lesson]

Comment: That cannot be done, Next.js throws an Error: Catch-all must be the last part of the URL.